# Monitor ramdisk throughput

Tags: linux, monitoring, ramdisk, tmpfs

I was wondering if there was a tool available to monitor the current ramdisk throughput. I found that with `sysstat`, `iostat`, etc. I am only able to monitor the current throughtput of physical devices.

What I'm looking for is a tool which generates an output indicating the current throughput. Something like:

```
DEV         write        read       overall
ramdisk-1   1.4 GB/s     0.4 GB/s   1.8 GB/sec
```

Do you guys have an suggestions on how to generate this metric?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the df command? If your volatiles are tmpfs organized, it's great. if they are ramfs oriented... you'll have to estimate the memory size from a free command I guess.

```
   diag@diag-gnu:~$ df -h
   Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
   udev               3,8G       0  3,8G   0% /dev
   tmpfs              769M    9,5M  760M   2% /run
   /dev/sda6           14G     11G  2,5G  81% /
   tmpfs              3,8G     27M  3,8G   1% /dev/shm
   tmpfs              5,0M    4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
   tmpfs              3,8G       0  3,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   /dev/sdb2           92G     22G   65G  26% /media/Ubuntu16
   /dev/sda7           11G    1,8G  8,7G  17% /home
   /dev/sda4           50G     36G   12G  76% /media/Ubuntu14
   /dev/sdc1          466G    334G  133G  72% /media/diag/My Passport
   /dev/sda3          386G    216G  170G  56% /media/diag/564E27DB4E27B2A3
```

Adishatz

Comment: df does not show throughput.